# How should I code two authors in a bibtex file as "Author1 WITH Author2"?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

So I have a book written by Author1 "with the collaboration of Author2".
Of course standard method would be just to cite:

> @book{Death:2004vg, title = {{Death and Time}}, author = {Author1},
>   publisher = {None}, year = {2039} }

However, the situation is not so clear since Author2 is keen to have her name included. As she is a reviewer for this article, I better comply. That being said, it is not accurate to express that as an AND relationship. Is there any nice solution?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is Author2 truly an author in the usual sense of the term? E.g., is he/she listed on the book's title page? Or is he/she more of a contributor?

Answer (score 6):

I would use the `editor` field for the second author and specify the `editortype` appropriately. You can either use one of the standard roles provided by `biblatex` or define your own. Here, I use `biblatex`'s `collaborator`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mybook,
    author  =   {Author, The Main},
    title   =   {This Is Not the Title of This Book},
    publisher   =   {Ragged Papyrus},
    address     =   {Nowhere},
    editor  =   {Collaborator, The},
    editortype  =   {collaborator}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \autocite{mybook}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: authors and collaborators]

## EDIT

If you need the collaborator listed in the labels for an author-year style, one way would be to redefine the labels. However, since this is probably not something you need repeatedly, I would just use the `shortauthor` field:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{mybook,
    author  =   {Author, The Main},
    shortauthor =   {{Author with Collaborator}},
    title   =   {This Is Not the Title of This Book},
    publisher   =   {Ragged Papyrus},
    address     =   {Nowhere},
    editor  =   {Collaborator, The},
    editortype  =   {collaborator},
    year    =   1066,
  }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\begin{document}
  \autocite{mybook}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Author-Year labels with collaboration]

Comment: Nice! But, if at all possible, I need it to appear in the text as "yaddah yaddah" (Author1 with Author2, 2013). Is that possible? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @mateuz See my edit.